# Add multiple marker on google map and show Infowindow whenever I click on any marker on google map

Tags: javascript

I want to able to add multiple marker on the google map and when I click on any of them, it will show an infoWindow the location of the marker. However, the issue I am facing is not able to enable the infoWindow to pop up when any of the marker is clicked.

Please see my codes below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Google Map Marker</h1>

        <div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>

        <script>

            const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            let labelIndex = 0;

            function initMap() {
                const defaultLoc = { lat:1.31170, lng:103.77495 };
                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: defaultLoc
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", (event) => {
                    addMarker(event.latLng, map);
                })

                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: { lat:1.31170, lng:103.77495 },
                    map: map,
                });

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

                        infoWindow.setContent("<p>Marker Location:" + marker.getPosition() + "</p>");
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    
                });
            }

            function addMarker(location, map) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
                    map: map,
                });
            }

            window.initMap = initMap;

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<google map api key>&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see a lot of examples where the location of multiple markers added to the google map are stored in an array. if the program allows to add multiple markers on the fly, how do I get a list of locations of all the markers that are added to the google map? With that, I will able to implement a For loop to iterate these markers to listen for click event on any of these markers. I went through Google map tutorials but I don't see any example of this.